# Warum hat die Wahrheit nur ein Auge?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Warum heißt die Redewendung *der Wahrheit ins Auge sehen* und nicht *der Wahrheit in die Augen sehen*?

Comment: Oder: Dem Tode ins Auge schauen; Der Tatsache ins Auge sehen; ein Auge auf etwas werfen. Evtl. hilfreich zum weiteren ableiten.

Comment: Auge in Auge...

Answer (score 8):

Ich sehe mindestens zwei Gründe:

- Ganz genau genommen wäre hier weder Singular noch Plural sondern der **Dualis** angebracht, eine Sonderform des Numerus für die Anwendung bei paarweise vorkommenden Teilen (wie bei gerne bei Körperteilen: Armen, Beinen, Ohren). Diese Form ist offenbar seit dem Sanskrit auf dem Rückzug, hat aber als Konzept ihren Abdruck in späteren Sprachen hinterlassen. Wie dieser Zwitter auf die überlebenden Numeri abgebildet wird, hat eine willkürliche Komponente.
- Das Sehorgan wird aus naheliegenden Gründen mit dem kompletten Wahrnehmungskanal identifiziert. Würde man wirklich den Augapfel meinen, müsste man das präziser formulieren; eine solche konkrete Formulierung stünde aber im krassen Gegensatz zu einem Abstraktum wie *Wahrheit* oder *Gerechtigkeit*. Weitere Beipiele: Ein Musikstück schmeichelt **dem Ohr**, man fürchtet **den Arm** des Gesetzes (hier dann nicht Wahrnehmungskanal, sondern Durchsetzungsorgan). Ich bin nicht sicher, ob *ein Auge auf etwas haben* in die gleiche Kategorie fällt, das hier m. E. nur ein *Teil* der Aufmerksamkeit gemeint ist

Comment: Punkt 1 ist wohl eine Überlegung zum Thema aber kein Grund. Man (Bogart) sagt ja auch "Ich schau Dir in die Augen, Kleines!"

Comment: @userunknown: Eigentlich sagt Bogart zu Bergmann: »*Here's looking at you, Kid!*«, und das ist ein Trinkspruch, der eigentlich nichts anders als »Prost!« bedeutet. Die Übersetzung für die deutsche Synchronisation erfolgte »auf dem Dienstweg«: Der Übersetzer hat den Text übersetzt, ohne dabei die Filmszene zu sehen, und hat die englische Phrase wörtlich übersetzt, offenbar ohne den eigentlichen Sinn (»Prost!«) zu erfassen. Der Synchronsprecher hat dann ganz einfach brav den vorgegebenen deutschen Text möglichst lippensynchron aufgesagt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Gut zu wissen. Bogart war wohl auch nicht der Urheber des engl. Satzes, sondern der Drehbuchautor. Der Übersetzer hat also einen anderen Sinn vermutet und nicht "Ich schau Dir ins Auge, Kleines" erdichtet, sondern - s.o. Btw.: Was heißt denn "Here's looking at you, Kid"? Jetzt nicht eingedampft auf "Prost".

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. +1 dafür. Punkt 1 war sehr interessant, vor allem da ich Dualis bisher nicht kannte, und klingt nicht unwahrscheinlich. Dass hier nicht der Augapfel, sondern das Sehorgan im Allgemeinen gemeint ist, ist mir klar. Das ist für mich aber kein Grund warum hier die Einzahl verwendet wird. Ich werde die Antwort nicht akzeptieren, da ich gerne irgendeinen Beleg hätte.

Comment: Schön, wie hier der Sprache auf den Zahn gefühlt wird

Answer (score 4):

Einzahl anstatt Mehrzahl

Die antike Rednerkunst (Rhetorik) hat die Möglichkeiten der Stilmittel oder rhetorischen Figuren sehr genau untersucht und geradezu zu einem Lehrfach ausgebaut. Die Einzahl anstelle der Mehrzahl zu verwenden war so ein rhetorischer Kniff, um sich etwas anders auszudrücken als es in Normalsprache üblich war. Dieses Stilmittel hat sich in vielen Redewendungen erhalten.

[Stilmittel](http://www.lingualatina.de/poesis/stilmittel.htm)